# Single for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to create a single for-loop instead of using a nested for this question.

**Required**: fill up Matrix (foo) with multiples of loopvec1 and loopvec2 using a **single** for loop.

So far, I am only able to solve it using *nested* for loops. Here are my codes:

```
loopvec1 <- 5:7
loopvec2 <- 9:6

foo <- matrix(NA, length(loopvec1), length(loopvec2))

for (i in 1:length(loopvec1)) {
   for (j in 1:length(loopvec2)) {
   foo[i, j] <- loopvec1[i] * loopvec2[j]
  }
}

foo
```

Output (foo):

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   45   40   35   30
[2,]   54   48   42   36
[3,]   63   56   49   42
```

May I know how do I achieve the same results just by using a **single** for loop instead?

Edit: I am aware that there is another function "outer" that produces the same result (which resulted in this question being marked as a duplicate), however, the question that I am stuck with requires me to use a single **for** loop instead of any other functions.

Comment: `outer(loopvec1, loopvec2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
loopvec1 <- 5:7
loopvec2 <- 9:6

foo <- matrix(NA, length(loopvec1), length(loopvec2))

for (i in 1:length(loopvec1)) {
      foo[i,] <- loopvec1[i] * loopvec2
  }


foo
```

results:

```
> foo
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   45   40   35   30
[2,]   54   48   42   36
[3,]   63   56   49   42
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks! However, I don't understand this part of the code "foo[i,] <- loopvec1[i] * loopvec2"

Comment: so if you evaluate you code above, i just removed the loop containing j and all the values that referenced j. `foo[i,]` is saying for the i in the sequence 1:3, each row in foo should multiply each value of loopvec1[i] to all the values in loopvec2. I am fairly new to R, so this is the best i can explain it.